# TRIDION UI 2012 GetUserSettings

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

We are installing SDL Tridion UI 2012 on both CM and CD side with SP1 HR1 fix with the below set up :

1) We have a cd_preview_webservice JSP website configured: 
2) A JSP staging website

However the problem is that we not able to see the SDL Tridion BUTTON on the staging website for the page with Site Edit enabled.

Enabling firebug when loading the page we see below problem :

The bootstrap script is loaded but we don’t see the button because the bootstrap script connect to the wrong URL as shown below (it should conenct to CM server a not staging server ??)

http://[contentDeliveryWebServer]/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings  404 Not found

While the bootstrap is loaded correctly from the content manager server
(http://[contentManagerWebserver]/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Editor.aspx/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js)

Can you please give us a hint why the BUTTON is not showing on the staging website?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by David, the script is situated on the Content Manager server.

John Winter has written an excellent blog post on the SDL Tridion Developer website on "[SDL Tridion UI – Template Building Block set up for easier content porting](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/sdl-tridion-ui-template-building-block-set-up-for-easier-content-porting)".  I would highly recommend following this approach as it will make moving this between environment as lot easier.

(+1 for using Firebug and supplying useful debug information)

Answer (score 5):

The bootstrap script should indeed be loaded from the Content Manager Explorer.

In the User Interface Update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 manual, under "[Enabling editing for a set of Web pages](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_sharedenabset0923DC2A8E3748538314E5543E142F1D)", it states that you should specify the **Content Manager Explorer** url as the "SiteEdit Editor URL" parameter on the "Enable inline editing for Page" TBB in your page template.

Can you check this?